# How i can make like this widget, in which when data grow up the last two item come down automatic

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make like this widget, in which when data grow up the last two item come down automatic and the size increase.

I don't want to use a fixed size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you should not use a fixed size. You need to use a `ListView`

Assuming your items are in a List (e.g. of String to keep it simple):

```
  List myInvoice = [];
  myInvoice.add("Haircut Fee");
  myInvoice.add("Beard Shave Fee");
  //...
  myInvoice.add("Tax");
```

Then, display in a `ListView`

```
  ListView.builder(
    itemCount: myInvoice.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTile(leading: myInvoice[index]);
    }
  );
```

If you get the logic, you can modify the List to hold objects more complex than a String, or use two lists.

More [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

Comment: my answer about how i can add this listview inside column and increase size according num of item in liseview